# Desktop not loading after booting

Tags: apt, updates, 18.04

When i rebooted my computer, it has decided to install the new update and now I have a problem making it boot to the GUI. All that it shows is the terminal window. 
I have tried running `startx` but no change. And then I tried

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get upgrade -V 
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -V
$ sudo reboot
```

in case some of the packages didn't install properly but for every package I get `Failed to fetch...`

or `$ sudo apt install update-manager-core` gives `Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-mising`

Any idea what might be going wrong here or how this issue can be solved?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen 18.04.1 LTS